# how to check if a background is a gradient or a solid color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

need to check if a clicked element has a gradient or a solid color as its background

```js
$('.title').on('click', function(){
  if($(this).background.isGradient){  // how to say this?
  console.log('gradient');
  }
  else{console.log('solid color');}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='title' style='background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1)); padding:14px 9px 9px 9px; color:black;'>LOREM</div>
<br>
<div class='title' style='background-color:orange; padding: 9px 5px; color:white;'>IPSUM</div>
```

Comment: do you consider `linear-gradient(red,red)` to be a gradient or a solid color? because it can be both

Comment: @TemaniAfif - I see but for the above purpose it would be a gradient

Comment: then do a text search to see if `linear-gradient` is inside `background`

Comment: @TemaniAfif - not possible, because in one case is `background` and in another - `background-color`

Comment: background is the longhand property, it doesn't matter if you set background-color, background-image, etc .. the result of the computed value will be inside background the same way. Print the result of the computed value in both case to notice this (I insist on *computed value*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".title").each(function() {
    if ($(this).css("background").match(/gradient/)) {
      console.log('gradient');
    } else {
      console.log('solid color')
    }

  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='title' style='background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1)); padding:14px 9px 9px 9px; color:black;'>LOREM</div>
<div class='title' style='background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1)); padding:14px 9px 9px 9px; color:black;'>LOREM</div>
<div class='title' style='background:#f00; padding:14px 9px 9px 9px; color:black;'>LOREM</div>
```

Explanation: You loop through all items with the class `.title` and read the css background property with `$(this).css("background")` - if this contains the string "gradient", its a gradient, if not, its not.

This however doesn't account for a gradient from red to red for example, which technically will be a gradient, but shows as solid color.

(probably not important to you at all)

*And yes, as stated below, the regex `/gradient/` might produce false positives in some cases (filenames containing the word 'gradient' for example). Just come up with a more complex regex for your exact scenario then. The general concept however remains the same.*

Comment: Good solution, but there are some cases where it may give incorrect results, in example : `style='background:url("video-game-gradient.jpg")'`

Comment: True. Feel free to come up with a more complex match regex (like /linear-gradient/ for example :P), but the concept remains the same.

Comment: I wouldn't use RegEx to parse such strings to make sure `gradient` is not included in something else that what OP is looking for

Comment: Well, `/linear-gradient/` will match `url("blabla-linear-gradient-blabla.jpg")`, but again, this should be very rare cases

Comment: Whats your point? Just write up your own answer, if you have a better solution? This surely works for the given case and answers the question "how to say this" in jquery. It can be easily adopted for more complex scenarios.

Comment: Well, my point is that I'm sure **your** answer can be improved. I just found that the gradients are stored in `background-image`. Then, `.css("background-image")` will limit the string to parse. A RegEx such as `/^linear-gradient/` could be enough, but there are things such as `-webkit-gradient`

Comment: I added your objection to my answer, feel free to use my code to take this to the next level. From my experience coding is most of the time about finding solutions for a certain scenario and move on to the next problem. But well, thats just me (oh, and the OP, who accepted this answer as helpful 5 comments ago)

Comment: That's not an objection, your answer is actually good, as I stated in my first comment, but there are flaws